# create html page using awk command

Tags: html, shell, awk, cgi

I am using below command to create html page using below awk command

```
`awk -F, 'BEGIN {print "<tbody>"} ; {  print "<tr><td bgcolor='$bgcol'><center><a href=http://10.0.0.1/cgi-bin/categ?$1>" $1 "</a></center></td><td bgcolor='$bgcol'><center>" $2 "</center></td></tr>"} ; END { print "</tbody>"}' /tmp/temps/sitecount`
```

below are contents of sitecount file example

`Traditional Religions,10`

When running above command i am getting below output

`<tr><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC><center><a href=http://10.0.0.1/cgi-bin/categ?$1>Traditional Religions</a></center></td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC><center>10</center></td></tr>`

But i need this output

`<tr><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC><center><a href=http://10.0.0.1/cgi-bin/categ?Traditional Religions>Traditional Religions</a></center></td><td bgcolor=#DCDCDC><center>10</center></td></tr>`

I need to pass value "Traditional Religions' to my cgi script and not "$1"

Comment: `print ".../categ?$1>" $1 "</a>...` -- remove the $1 in quotes.

Comment: not working. output is same

Comment: Voting to close as a typo. Glad you found a solution to your problem. Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem resolved by changing this

`<a href=http://10.0.0.1/cgi-bin/categ?"$1">`